# unable to lauch an instance from the command line for oracle bare metal cloud

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'm trying to launch an instance using the script which is given in the 
below URL https://github.com/oracle/terraform-provider-baremetal/tree/master/docs/examples/compute/single_instance.
I have made modifications in the env-var file to point it our tenancy, compartment, subnet, finger printer, user ocid etc. When I run 'terraform plan and apply it throws me the below error.

Error:
baremetal_core_volume.TFBlock0: Status: 400; Code: LimitExceeded; Message: The limit for this tenancy has been exceeded.

baremetal_core_instance.TFInstance: Status: 400;  Code: InvalidParameter;   Message: Invalid format for ssh public key

Answer (score 3):

You are getting two unrelated error messages -

The first - "Status: 400; Code: LimitExceeded;" means you have exceeded the limit on resources your tenancy has access to. You can see the default limits here - 
https://docs.us-phoenix-1.oraclecloud.com/Content/General/Concepts/servicelimits.htm 
and a reference to that error code here - 
https://docs.us-phoenix-1.oraclecloud.com/Content/API/References/apierrors.htm. 
Contact your Oracle Cloud sales contact to get your limit raised. You can also reach out directly to me and I'll find the right person.

The second - "Status: 400; Code: InvalidParameter; Message: Invalid format for ssh public key" means the public key you are sending is malformed. For documentation on creating a key - https://docs.us-phoenix-1.oraclecloud.com/Content/GSG/Tasks/creatingkeys.htm. Generally with this error message we find customers are inadvertently sending the private half of their key.